# VS2008 devenv not closing, keeping files from being built?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, msbuild

Hey guys, have you guys run into this behavior, and if so, how have you gotten around it?

Basically, what's happening is this: I'll have a VS2008 instance running, pop into another VS project in a new instance, and then close the new instance. After that, every once in a while VS will complain that "File  is open in another window, would you like to close it?". Clicking yes doesn't do anything; I can't open the file in the editor.

What's infinitely worse is that, any files which would display that behavior (which maybe ones I don't know about) seem to not get built. The assembly just straight up doesn't include the classes which are displaying the issue.

I've noticed that when I close VS there're still instances of devenv.exe running; when I kill them in Process Explorer, the issues seem to disappear, so it seems to me that they're keeping file handles open.

I'd love to be able to trust my environment a little more than I can right now...

Any suggestions?

PS - I have the VimEmu installed, and that's the only plugin.

Answer (score 1):

The obvious question: Have you tried to uninstall/disable the 3rd party plugin to see if that changes anything?

Comment: I disabled it, and it didn't seem to do anything. I haven't gone so far as uninstalling, but if I nothing else, I'll try it.

Comment: Are you running VS 2008 SP1? A long shot, but how about anti-virus software, if using, have you tried to disable it to see any difference in behaviour?

Comment: I am, and I'll see what happens; I'm running ClamWin

Answer (score 1):

One thing you can try to get around the issue (so you don't have to close down) is to run unlocker on the affected files.

http://www.emptyloop.com/unlocker/

It is a free tool that allows you to see what has a files locked and then can force an unlock.

Not a fix for your issue, but it maybe a work around.

As a side note when I change a file in a second instance of Visual Studio I get this message:

**This File has been modified outside of the Source Editor.**

**Do you want to reload it?**

Comment: awesome tool -  but I don't think it support 64 bit unfortuanetly.